# Giving php permission to execute java commands

Tags: php, exec

I am tryng to execute java command from php, but the output array keeps returning empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code that i have tried

```
<?php


    exec( "/usr/bin/java -version",$output);


    print_r($output);

    ?>
```

Also i checked the error log and found the following

```
sh: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
```

and when i try the code

```
<?php


    exec( "java -version",$output);


    print_r($output);

    ?>
```

i get

```
sh: java: command not found
```

what should i do to allow my php file to execute java commands?

Comment: `chmod +x /usr/bin/java` and try

Comment: It still gives the same permission denied.

Comment: What is your actual requirement ? Just checking java version?

Comment: Harikrishnan, i want to execute certain java commands, but the most simplest the java version command isnt executing.

Comment: Can you specify some of those commands? I have an alternative solution for you.

Comment: I want to execute command like Java -jar apache-tika.jar test.doc, basically commands related to apache-tika

Comment: Do u need to pass params from php script to java command?

Comment: I would need to pass it the file name, so i wanted to make use of exec so i could create the command on the fly and pass it

Comment: Any suggestion  Harikrishnan?

Comment: Ya. Will update you after sometime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50658/discussion-between-harikrishnan-and-opensource-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)  to execute the java program.

1)write argument name to a file from your php program.

```
 $Handle = fopen("myfile", 'w');
 fwrite($Handle, "argument");
 fclose($Handle);
```

2) Create a bash script to read that argument name and run java program.

```
#!/bin/sh
arg=$(head -n 1 myfile)   
/usr/bin/java  argument 2>&1
>myfile
```

save it as mycron.sh

`chmod +x mycron.sh`

3) Configure the script in crontab

`crontab -e` and paste this

```
* * * * * mycron.sh
```